# Загрузить данные из списка в одну колонку БД

Tags: python, sqlite

Подскажите, как вставить сразу все данные из списка?

Например, есть код и данные `l`. Как вставить сразу все значения `l` в таблицу в отдельной колонке?

```
import sqlite3 
import random 

k=0
n=''
l=[]
while k<5:
    n=str(random.randint(1000000000000,9234567891011))
    k+=1
    l+=str(n).split()

conn = sqlite3.connect("baza02") 
cursor = conn.cursor()    
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE albums( ID)""")    
albums = [(l)]    
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO albums VALUES (?)", albums)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Цикл for Вам в помощь.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, тут цикл не нужен!

Comment: @MaxU но в Вашем решении он есть. Еще и памяти отжирает больше, чем обычный цикл.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, о каком обычном цикле вы говорите? Вы предлагаете использовать `cursor.execute()` вместо `cursor.executemany()`?

Comment: @MaxU все зависит от требований к производительности и ресурсов потребляемых кодом. Если производительность и плевать на ресурсы - executemany() годно в этом случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании `cursor.executemany()` надо указывать список кортежей в качестве параметров - один кортеж на каждую запись:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO albums VALUES (?)", [(x,) for x in l])
```

или

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO albums VALUES (?)", map(lambda x: (x,), l))
```

но лучше создавать список кортежей вот так:

```
parms = [(random.randint(1000000000000,9234567891011),) for _ in range(5)]
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO albums VALUES (?)", parms)
```

вы же указали список списков состоящий из *одного* элемента - в данном случае это соответствует одной строке из пяти столбцов, вместо необходимых пяти строк из одного столбца:

```
In [17]: albums
Out[17]:
[['4927540484355',
  '1584364840864',
  '1924451984520',
  '5202721799397',
  '7225191647986']]
```

Comment: а как же "цикл не нужен"?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, `map(lambda x: (x,), l)` - функциональный стиль без цикла...

Comment: Cпасибо большое, буду пробовать..

Comment: [(x,) for x in l]) - создается список, который еще и память  кушает в соответствии с своим размером. Можете проверить.

Comment: cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO albums VALUES (?)", [(x,) for x in l]) вот так получилось!! Спасибо огромное

Comment: А что бы сделать два, три столбца и тоже данные с For ? Через запятую? cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO albums VALUES (?,?)", [(x,) for x in l], [(y,) for y in l2])?

Comment: @Елена, лучше в __одном__ цикле сразу подготовить кортежи для всех значений и потом передать `executemany()` - `cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO albums VALUES (?,?)", parms)`

Comment: Поняла. А если у меня должно быть несколько столбцов и данные разные? Тоже с for , но в другом столбце, колонке..

Comment: @Елена `params = zip(l, l2)`

Comment: @Елена, я думаю лучше задать отдельный вопрос и описать в нем как вы получаете данные для разных столбцов - возможно есть более элегантное решение...

Comment: Поняла. Спасибо, сделаю!)